# Unexpected BigDecimal result. 1 divided by 3 results in 1. Unsure why

Tags: java, bigdecimal, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Addition for BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846900/addition-for-bigdecimal)

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but cannot figure out what it is. I'm trying to use `BigDecimal` to get the decimal portion of a division between two numbers. A very simple case, 1.00 divided by 3.00 should be 0.(3) repeating. However, I keep getting a result of 1.00.

```java
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(1.00).setScale(2);
BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal(3.00).setScale(2);

num.divide(divisor, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

System.out.print(num);
```

My result is 1.00 and I can't figure out why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result of `num.divide` is ignored.  You need to set that back into a variable

```
    BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(1.00).setScale(2);
    BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal(3.00).setScale(2);

    BigDecimal result = num.divide(divisor, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

    System.out.print(result);
```

This prints `0.33`

Comment: +1 You have to do this as BigDecimal (and BigInteger which it uses) is immutable.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I totally missed that despite it being the very first word in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

BigDecimals are immutable. You need to assign the result to the variable.

Answer (score 2):

`num.divide` doesn't change `num` it returns the result.

Try:

```
num = num.divide(divisor, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```