# Why does int + BigDecimal not work?

Tags: java

I encountered this problem, which was that I couldn't add an integer to a BigDecimal. In the code, I looked at the error and it said "bad operand types for binary operator '+'". How do I add integer to BigDecimal? (Represented in code as 1 + sqf)

```
BigDecimal sqf = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(5));
sqf.setScale(100);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal((1 + sqf) / 2); //Error here (1 + sqf)
bd.setScale(100);
System.out.println(isBuzzNumber(77707));
System.out.println(findHypotenuse(9, 10));
System.out.println("Phi (φ) = " + bd);
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? Java doesn't have overloaded operators.

Answer (score 3):

`BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.ONE.add(sqf).divide(new BigDecimal(2))`

Standard operators apply to primitives only.

Answer (score 3):

1. Java doesn't have operator overloading, thus any standard operator applies to primitive type only
2. BigDecimal isn't included in the autoboxing mechanism, because it doesn't have primitive type representation
3. Read up [BigDecimal API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), it implements mathematical operators as methods (which mostly requires another `BigDecimal` instance as operand.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to cast in either of the formats. BigDecimal is immutable.

For instance

```
sqf = sqf.add(new BigDecimal(1));
```

You can add by constructing a new BigDecimal class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846900/addition-for-bigdecimal shows a great example

Answer (score 1):

Math signs (+-*/) are only available for String and [primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in Java.
BigDecimal and BigInteger are not primitive types, so you can not use math signs directly with them.
Consider using methods of instance instead when you want to do math calculate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BigDecimal out of an integer using [the `BigDecimal(int)` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(int)), as in `new BigDecimal(1)` or `BigDecimal.ONE` (thanks, Herp Derpington).

Like Integer and Double, `BigDecimal instances are *immutable*, which means that any one BigDecimal instance will never change value, and thus you can *share or reuse instances that represent the same number*.

Unlike Integer and Double, BigDecimal does not participate in *autoboxing*, which is the translation from `int` primitives to `Integer` object instances (and likewise across other types). In Java, operators like `+` and `/` apply only to primitives; though you can call `sqf.add(BigDecimal.ONE)`, there is no way to use `+` or call `sqf.add(1)`.

To operate on BigDecimal instances, you'll need to constrain yourself to its methods (such as `add` and `divide`), passing in BigDecimal instances (newly-created, if necessary). `divide`, in particular, offers a number of *method overloads* that allow you to choose the way that the number is rounded or scaled—which is one of its advantages over the built-in floating-point division; if you encounter trouble, you may want to specify [`ROUND_TO_EVEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN), which best matches [the IEEE 754 behavior in the Java Language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4).

Comment: Tried, but still not working. I made 1 into a bigdecimal, and it says the same thing. Help?

Comment: Yeah because you can't divide a BigDecimal using /

Comment: Then how would I divide? I tried using .divide but its showing me a whole list of constructors.

Comment: Updated answer: You shouldn't have to specify any other parameters to `divide`, but if you do, I'd suggest `ROUND_TO_EVEN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use BigDecimal object's intvalue() function like this:

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal((1 + sqf.intValue()) / 2);