# How to sum BigDecimal properties in java

Tags: java

Let's get a simple example:

```
 Class Foo{
     private BigDecimal item1;
     private BigDecimal item2;
     private BigDecimal item3;
     private BigDecimal item4;
     private BigDecimal item5;
//setters and getters
   public BigDecimal getTotal(){
       BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        if(null != item1){
            total =total .add(item1);
           }
        if(null != item2){
            total =total .add(item2);
           }
          ...
          ...
}
    }
```

I am summing in entity level. this is correct way or not?

can any one give me better code for getting total Value

Comment: put all the BigInteger in a list, and then loop for adding them all

Comment: make an array of BigDecimals and add them

Comment: looking for this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1846918/592817

Comment: You could use the streams API?  Pass them in as a list, filter for null and then reduce

Comment: Make sure their values are not null by intializing them as zero first?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `List<BigDecimal>`

```
public BigDecimal getTotal(){
    List<BigDecimal> values =  Arrays.asList(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)

    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (BigDecimal value : values) {
        if(value != null) {
            total = total.add(value);
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop to make your code simple :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

...

public BigDecimal getTotal(){
   BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO; 
   for(BigDecimal bd: Arrays.asList(item1,item2,item3,item4,item5)){
        if(null != bd){
            total =total .add(bd);
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed (and little) amount of numbers you can do as follows:

```
            total = total.add(item1 ==null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : item1).add(item2 ==null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : item2).add(item3 ==null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : item3);
```

Adding 0 if the item is null and the item itself otherwise. IF you have a variable amount of items, then you need to iterate over them in a array or something like this:

```
for (BigDecimal current : myBigDecimalArray){
   total = total.add(current ==null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : current );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using reflection:

```
public static BigDecimal sum(Object instance, String... fields) {
    BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (String field : fields) {
        BigDecimal value = getProperty(instance, field);
        if (value != null) {
            total = total.add(value);
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Sample:

```
    annex.setOrTot(ReflectionUtils.sum(annex, "orEstadoOrg", "orSs", "orCcaa", "orCorpLoc", "orResto"));
    annex.setIdpTot(ReflectionUtils.sum(annex, "idpEstadoOrg", "idpSs", "idpCcaa", "idpCorpLoc", "idpResto"));
    annex.setDrTot(ReflectionUtils.sum(annex, "drEstadoOrg", "drSs", "drCcaa", "drCorPloc", "drResto"));
    annex.setIdcTot(ReflectionUtils.sum(annex, "idcEstadoOrg", "idcSS", "idcCcaa", "idcCorPloc", "idCresto"));
```

Answer (score 0):

java 8+, could use stream api

```
BigDecimal total = itemList.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```